# How to restore repository after git push -force?

Tags: git, github

I was connected to my github repository but got the following error when I tried to push a file:

`To https://github.com/name/port.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/name/port.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.`

After looking through the guide, I found the -force option and forced a push:

`git push -f`

but now everything in that repository has been overwritten. How do I revert back to an earlier commit? Sorry, I'm new to github and I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `git reflog`. Git doesn't remove commits from its database until you run `git gc`.

```
git reflog
ABCD1234 HEAD@{0}: Boom goes the dynamite! Your repository is hosed!
...
EFGH5678 HEAD@{n}: Last known good commit
*shift + Q to exit*
git reset --hard EFGH5678
git push -f
```

Note: This has nothing to do with GitHub. This is behavior in Git itself you are noticing.

Comment: Appreciate the help, Greg. The `git reflog` function seems to only recover files deleted today. The rest of the respository, which was set up yesterday on a different machine, is still not recovered. Any insight into why that may be?

Comment: Can you clarify the use case of your question then? I'm not sure on which machine which commands were run.

Comment: Are you sure the reflog isn't showing you the commit where master used to be? I'm running `git reflog` and even `git log -g` locally and it is showing me _everything_, including interactive rebases.

Comment: These were my steps:

1) `git remote add origin https://github.com/name/port.git`
2) `git push -u origin master` #error here
3) `git branch clean_up`
4) `git checkout clean_up`
5) `git rm 'Rplot.png'`
6) `git commit -m 'remove rplot'`
7) `git checkout master`
8) `git merge clean_up`
9) `git branch -d clean_up`
10) `git push` #error here
11) `git push -f`